# Max number of databases per user in mysql

Tags: mysql

i was wondering if there is a way to limit the number of databases a user can create in mysql? I would like to give a user the right to create databases, but he should not be able to create an infinite number of databases.

Thanks,
Gerold

Comment: What is the level of access of these users?  Can you handle database creation through application logic but give the user less permissions?

Answer (score 0):

If your users only have granted permissions on their own databases, you can check `information_schema.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES` prior to permitting creation how many databases they already have.  However, for this to work, you would have to prohibit `CREATE DATABASE` by the users directly and instead create the databases in application code via another privileged database user then grant access to the users to their newly created databases.

```
SELECT 
  GRANTEE, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA) AS NUM_DBS
FROM information_schema.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES
GROUP BY GRANTEE
```

If `NUM_DBS` is greater than your limit, don't create a new database for them.

Note that if you are granting permissions to users for databases other than the ones they "own", you will need to account for that in your query by excluding those via something like

```
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('other','dbs','you','grant','access','on')
```